# How can I locate web element for mentioned code

Tags: selenium, automation

How can I locate web element in  selenium web driver for the below mentioned code

```
<a class="small" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()" true;="" return="" onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu1, '120px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" href="#">

    Patient ▾
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with xpath like one of the following

```
//a[@class='small']  

//a[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), 'Patient')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If its C#, you can use any one of these.

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("small"));    
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class='small']"));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[onclick='return clickreturnvalue()']"));
```